# Find record diff between two dates in Apex (to minimize API calls)

Tags: apex, api, governorlimits, history-tracking, diff

I have a managed package app with a `CustomObject__c` where some of its fields need to be "synced" with an external web service. To stay within technical limits the Sync callout is only done once a day.

I now want to find out which records of `CustomObject__c` have **changed in certain relevant fields** (So `LastModifiedDate` won't work) since the last callout and only sync those in the next run.

**Is there anything in Salesforce that I can use for that?**
I was thinking about using History Tracking, or a custom hash which I calculate on Trigger.

Comment: You've basically answered your own question. You'd have to use history tracking, write a trigger to keep track of specified field changes, or build a process builder/workflow to set some sort of flag.

Comment: @sfdcfox Didn't even know that this works. To get started easier...can you point me to any documentation example. Even if this works I am still not sure if that is a good solution. is History Tracking relyant. Can I package it and can subscribers deactivate it?

Answer (score 5):

Field History Tracking is the most obvious choice, but comes with significant caveats:

- Several field types that can't be tracked: [formula, roll-up summary, auto-number, created by, last mod by, AI Prediction](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&type=5), and [field values longer than 255 chars](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history.htm&type=5).
- "If a trigger causes a change on an object the current user doesn’t have permission to edit, that change is not tracked. Field history honors the permissions of the current user." (source same as last link)
- Field History Tracking can go in managed packages, but is doc'ed as [subscriber-modifiable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm). I don't know whether this includes removing tracking from a field that is packaged as tracked, or just being able to add additional tracked fields.
- Base limits of tracking 20 fields per object, for 18-24 months, which is extensible via the [Field Audit Trail](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2015/04/field-audit-trail-briefing-isvs.html) paid add-on.

All that said, the implementation would be pretty straightforward - a schedulable batch class that queries `CustomObject__history` based on a `CreatedDate` newer than the last run, and compiles and sends the changes to the external webservice.

Comment: N.B. testmethods for xxx__history objects are difficult as OldValue and NewValue can't be mocked ; requires mockable wrapper classes

Comment: Thomas would you mind adding a short code snippet to make this answer complete. I guess you have something flying around ;-) I'd really like to see how you efficiently compare states.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this Summer'19 improvement can help you : we can make an async trigger with Change Data Capture https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/06/get-buildspiration-with-asynchronous-apex-triggers-in-summer-19.html

For a solution without code, you can subscribe to the change events with a flow, and then call your web service https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_flow.htm

Please take into consideration the limits here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm

Correction : As you need to do the sync only once a day, with a trigger or a flow, you still have to use a flag to indicate that the record have to be synced.

Comment: CDC is more suitable when the external system understands that "protocol". But in my case the other system is as it is and doesn't understand th CDC format.

Comment: @RobertSösemann CDC can be implemented in an Apex trigger (e.g. `AccountChangeEvent`), which can then apply the appropriate logic for callout or setting a flag. I think this should work right even in an ISV context.

Comment: @sfdcfox why would I need CDC for that? I could even use a regular AfterUpdate trigger and set a flag on relevant changes, right?

Comment: @RobertSösemann The slight advantage of CDC is to avoid some additionnal execution time during the update of your custom object. The trigger (or the flow) can be executed asynchronously.

Comment: @sfdcfox: Cool that's right. I didn't think of that.